# How many concurrent users can the latest ejabberd XMPP server handle?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I want to build an instant messaging app and I need to know how many concurrent users can ejabberd xmpp server handle, the following are my server hardware specs:

1. CPU: 2x Intel Xeon E5 2630v4, 2 x 10 x 2.20 GHz
2. RAM: 256 GB REG ECC
3. Storage: 1TB SSD

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hard limit in ejabberd, it all depends whether the machine CPU and RAM can handle the load.

It is quite important if those accounts will generate traffic (have many contacts and change presence, and send messages), or will be almost quiet.

- Many accounts almost quiet: consume memory
- Few accounts chatting and changing presence a lot: consume processor

It is also important in the long term that you use a powerful SQL database instead of the internal Mnesia database (which is acceptable only for small servers).

You may want to run some benchmark tool, designed with your expected usage, to check ejabberd (or any other xmpp server).

For example, 18 years ago, I used jabsimul in a machine with one 1.7 GHz processor, less than 1 GB RAM, and it could handle thousands of chatty users perfectly:
https://www.ejabberd.im/benchmark/index.html